# Most common way to structure similar but unique ajax requests that depend on Django pk?

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-templates

(I'm using jquery and django)

Let's say I have a todo list, with each item having a unique primary key (pk). In the template, I list these items with a for loop so that each item is clickable, to display item details on another portion of the page (without reloading the entire page of course).

What is the generally accepted best way to do this?

I have tried multiple ways of "uniqueifying" each div, and multiple ways of passing this pk along in the ajax request.

**Part 1 - getting unique divs:**

- I put the pk as the suffix to each item div's id.  e.g.  {% for item
  in todolist %} stuff 
  $('body').on('click',"#item_{{item.pk}}", function(){var id = {{item.pk}}, .ajax stuff }) 
  {% endfor %}
- instead of suffixing pk, I add a custom html attribute called
  data-id. This allows me to use .attr("data-id") to get the pk from
  the clicked div and to remove the js from the for loop.
- instead of adding a custom html attribute, I add a hidden form field.

**Part 2 - passing pk to ajax request:**

- in the $.ajax() body, I set url: id+"/details" with the data field empty. In Django, I grab the id from the url regex definition.
- in the $.ajax() body, I set url: "/details" with data: {id:id}. In Django, I grab the id from inside views.py with request.POST['id'].
- in js, I just submit the form. Django gets the id as a form field.

So... with so many (probably bad) ways of doing this, which would you use?

Comment: You can use `.data("id")` instead of `.attr("data-id")`. But don't be confused they still have their differences

Comment: woah that's cool, didn't know that was built in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go for a single ajax function and it should be:

```
{% for item in todolist %}
    <div id="{{item.id}}" class="item_ajax" >{{item.name}}</div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    $('.item_ajax').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '{% url item_url %}',
              data: {'id': $(this).attr('id'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(response) {
                  // do something
              },
              error: function(rs, e) {
                  alert(rs.responseText);
              }
         }); 
    });
</script>
```

I have used a `class` selector, obviously you can choose what ever you like e.g. having a custom attribute but it should be common.

Comment: But with this implementation, there is the possibility of repeating ids. For example on the details pane, if another button that needs item.pk is needed, I wouldn't be able to use this method.

Comment: If you see i have used the `class` selector not the id selector. If another div has the `item_ajax` class then there is a problem. But you have to make sure the selector you used must not be used for other elements.

Comment: what I meant was, the page would not validate HTML if you used the same id in multiple divs, regardless of which selector you used. That's easily fixed by using data-id though, so w/e. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronZhang I don't see any issue if you have used the same id in multiple divs. I am getting the id of the `div` on which user has clicked `$(this).attr('id')` it will return me the id only of that div. You are confused I think.

Comment: I'm referencing [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) where it states "id = name [CS]
This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document."
You CANNOT have the same id in multiple divs.